# SQL Loader : Generate new log file each time

Tags: oracle, logging, sql-loader

I am using SQL Loader to import data from CSV file to a database table, and it works fine. Each time I run the command sqlldr, the log file is overridden with new infos.
Is there a way to add a timestamp or something to keep the archive of those log files instead of overriding the same file and without passing the value in the command params.

- .par file :

```
CONTROL=D:\projects\ctl\control.ctl
LOG=D:\projects\log\TRACK_MIGRATION.log
DATA=D:\projects\data\CUSTOMERS_SITES.csv
```

Want something like : ***TRACK_MIGRATION_20221229_113917.log***

Comment: Wrap the call to sqlldr in a script renaming the log file after execution?

Comment: That actually what I started doing, cause I think there is no native way to do it in sql loader. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long search, found no native way to automate naming the SQL Loader log file by adding a timestamp or something.

As mentioned above, I suggest wrapping the command line in a script that will take the responsibility of renaming your log file after it gets generated, or using the `log=` command line param which is a bit frustrating if you are running your command often.

For my case I found that our client use VBScript for such things in the server, so I decided using it to wrap my command line.

```vb
'Running SQL Loader command line
Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
oShell.run "sqlldr userid=" & DBLogin & "/" & DBPwd & "@" & DBName & " parfile=parfile.par"
Set oShell = Nothing

'Renaming the log file (TRACK_MIGRATION_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.log)
Dim FSO
Dim todayDate
todayDate = Year(Now) & Month(Now) & Day(Now) & "_" & Hour(Now) & Minute(Now) & Second(Now)
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
FSO.MoveFile "TRACK_MIGRATION.log", "TRACK_MIGRATION_" & todayDate & ".log"
```

Answer (score 1):

You must modify the startup script to remove the log parameter from the parameter file and add the log parameter to the command line.

.par file

```
CONTROL=D:\projects\ctl\control.ctl
DATA=D:\projects\data\CUSTOMERS_SITES.csv
```

command line

```
sqlldr user/password@DB parfile=parfile.par log=log_%date%_%time:~0,2%%time:~3,2%%time:~6,2%.log
```

log file

```
29.12.2022  20:06             1 262 log_29.12.2022_200657.log
29.12.2022  20:12             1 262 log_29.12.2022_201224.log
```

Comment: Yes, it will work, but as I mentioned, it is not the way that I want to use, because each time I need to specify the log param